# What units does DbGeometry.Distance return?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, geometry, geospatial

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeometry.distance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just defines the return value as:

> A double value that specifies the distance between the two closest
>   points in this geometry value and other.

What units are returned?  When testing the values do not match to anything I recognise and does not work in a WHERE clause.

```
var results = db.Locations.Where(t => t.ItemPoint.Distance(targetPoint) <= 100); // 100km
```

Note: *I am using MySQL with Entity Framework using the .NET Connector, which doesn't support using SRID values.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the MSDN documentation could do with a little more information, it doesn't specify the measurement of the value as it changes dependant on the SRID (or lack thereof).

Without an SRID, Geometry simply works on a flat grid (or planar) system (think old school square paper).  Your distance answers are therefore simple pythagoras results of

**a2 + b2 = c2** >>>>>> **c = SqRt(a2 + b2)**.

For example:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

DbGeometry geom1 = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(0 0)");
DbGeometry geom2 = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(50 50)");

Console.WriteLine(geom1.Distance(geom2));

//Returns 70.71067811 (the square root of (50 sq'd + 50 sq'd)).
```

You'll find this [blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/) an interesting read, skip to halfway down the page and you'll find how to create a user-defined haversine calculation method which will allow you to convert the results to distances.

Be warned though, If you can't map Stored Procedures in EF for MySQL, then you'll need to resort to good old fashioned ADO to get the results.  Make sure you use **st_distance** over **mbr_distance** as st_distance will be exact and mbr_distance will contain false positives.  You will need MySQL 5.6.1 for st_distance.

Lastly, if at all possible, consider another database if Spatial data is important.